# Run a loop to generate variable names in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

**I'm trying to import datasets which have the following filenames (phone1, phone2, etc)**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\phone1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\phone2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\phone3.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\phone4.csv')
df5 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\phone5.csv')
df6 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\phone6.csv')
```

**I tried the following code**

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    'df'+i = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\siddhn\Desktop\phone'+str(i)+'.csv', engine = 'python')
```

But I get an error saying that **cannot assign to operator**

**How to import the datasets using a loop.?**

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, create a list `dfs = []` and use `dfs.append( pd.read_csv(...) )`.  Now, you can use `dfs[0]` to refer to one specifically, but you can loop through them easily using `for df in dfs:`.

Comment: As @TimRoberts mentioned you can store your DataFrames in list, but if it essential for your DataFrames to have specific names, using dict in a loop also possible. Something like that could be made (inside your for loop): dfs[f"df_{i}"] = pd.read_csv(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inbuilt `glob` package

```
from glob import glob

fullpath = f'C:\Users\siddhn\Desktop\phone[1-6].csv'
dfs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob(fullpath)]

print(dfs[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

As @TimRoberts mentioned, you should use a `list` or a `dict`to store your dataframes but if you really want to have variable `df1`, `df2`, ..., `df6`, you can use `locals()` or `globals()`:

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    locals()[f'df{i}'] = pd.read_csv(fr'C:\Users\siddhn\Desktop\phone{i}.csv')

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Comment: While using `locals()` may solve your problem, it will make your code messy and difficult to comprehend.

Comment: @Vishnudev. I'm totally agree with you

Answer (score 1):

you can store it in a list, here is the idea

```
var = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    var.append(i)

print(var[0])
print(var[2])
```

and from the list you can access the value using their key.

Answer (score 0):

`'df'+i` return a lvalue, i.e that can be assigned to other variables but cannot store some contents.
insted of using

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    'df'+i = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\siddhn\Desktop\phone'+str(i)+'.csv', engine = 'python')
```

create a List of data_frames as
`df = []`
Now append your data_frames as

```
for i in range(7):
   df.append(pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\siddhn\Desktop\phone'+str(i)+'.csv', engine = 'python')
```

You can then acess data_frames by indexing them like `df[0]` or `df[1]`.....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of data frames and then iterate over it or access by index.

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\siddhn\Desktop\phone'+str(i)+'.csv', engine = 'python') for i in range(1, 7)]
df_list[1]
```

The variable cannot be an operator thats the reason you get the error.